# Help regarding Ac current limiting using resistor

Tags: current, resistors, ac, resistance

I've 12v(Vrms) 1A  AC transformer. I need to regulate it to 1to 4ma maximum output without having much voltage drop.
Output load is an animal skin which has resistance in it.

Can I just use a resistor in series?
When I used 560Ohms, more current is passed through my hands.
Anyway to calculate currect resistor values,?

Comment: Ohms law R=V/I : 12/0.004 = 3000 Ohms. But I think you had better tell us what you are planning to do with passing current through animal skin as there maybe many more pitfalls then just setting a current. Especially as you don't seem to be familiar with Ohms law...

Comment: Do you need to limit it to 1-4ma RMS or peak?  It sounds like you need to use a controlled current source, as the resistance of the "animal skin" will vary significantly.

Comment: Any resistance you add in series with your load WILL reduce the voltage.

Comment: *I need to regulate it to 1to 4ma maximum output without having much voltage drop.* <-- these are contradictary requirements.

Answer (score 1):

> I need to regulate it to 1to 4ma maximum output without having much
>   voltage drop... Can I just use a resistor in series?

No. A resistor works linearly according to [Ohm's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohm%27s_law). Resistance = Voltage / Current, so for a maximum (short circuit) current of 4 mA the resistance needs to be  12 / 0.004 = 3000Ω. However at 1 mA the resistor would drop 3000 * 0.001 = 3V, so output voltage would drop from 12V to 9V.

I you want a fairly stable 12V up to 4 mA *and no more* then you need a circuit that starts dropping the voltage only when current exceeds 4 mA. Doing this to AC current is further complicated by the fact that 4 mA AC is actually a sine wave varying from -5.66 mA to +5.66 mA. Most current limiting circuits also have significant voltage drop (typically 1~2 V minimum) which distorts the AC waveform as it crosses the zero voltage point, and might require a higher input voltage to make up for the loss.

Here's an AC current regulation circuit that has minimal voltage drop below the current limit. A bridge rectifier formed by D1-D4 converts the AC voltage to DC so the current mirror (formed by Q1 and Q2) can work on both halves of the waveform. D5 and C1 half-wave rectify and smooth the AC input, producing ~+16V which is applied to R1 to produce a reference current of ~+5mA for the current mirror. The load (here represented by a variable resistor) is inserted on the AC side of the bridge rectifier.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f48S4a.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

With matched transistors Q2 should sink the same current as Q1 if it is able to. If the load current is less than the reference current then Q2 saturates with a low voltage drop. The bridge rectifier uses Schottky diodes for low voltage drop, so the rms AC output voltage and current varies from ~11.6 V at 1 mA to 11.4 V at 3.8 mA. At 4 mA current limiting starts to kick in and voltage drops to 10.8 V. Short circuit current is ~5.6 mA rms.

To vary the current limit simply change the value of R3 according to the formula Resistance = (16 V - 0.6 V) / Current. The 0.6 V accounts for voltage drop across Q1.

Q1 and Q2 should be in close thermal contact to ensure that they track well as temperature changes.

Comment: Thanks so much brother, btw, this produces pure sinewave right?

Comment: The circuit limits instantaneous current. When below the limit the output is a pure sine wave. Above the limit it progressively flattens the tops and bottoms of the waveform. If you need a 'pure' sine wave during current limiting then a more sophisticated circuit will be required. Note that the output of a transformer might not be a 'pure' sine wave either.